# Sharepoint Jquery crawl onload

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

If i add jquery onload function on a masterpage something like this:
object.onload=function(){myScript};

My purpose of this is that after a crawl a noindex tag be added to a particular tag.
So, will the crawl detect the no index that i place in the jquery.